# Приложения вылетает

Tags: android, android-xml, androidx, android-appcompat, android-app-compat-activity

Я мигрировал проект на андроид x и проект билдится но когда я запускаю он вылетает и вадает эту ошибку.

```
12/10 14:07:22: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 (Edited) API 24.
Install successfully finished in 8 s 332 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "activity.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 5230 on device 'Pixel_2_Edited_API_24 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2678)
        at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:896)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at void LoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LoginActivity.java:41)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kg.itservice.eprotocol-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/kg.itservice.eprotocol-2/lib/x86, /data/app/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2678)
        at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:896)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at void LoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LoginActivity.java:41)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12539(774KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 27MB/27MB, paused 15.363ms total 41.732ms
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process:  PID: 5230
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class TextInputLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class TextInputLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class TextInputLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.TextInputLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kg.itservice.eprotocol-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/lib/x86, /data/app/-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:700)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at kg.itservice.smartpolice.activity.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Мой xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".activity.LoginActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/loginForm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="108dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/login_logo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/authorization"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/range_20"
                android:text="АВТОРИЗАЦИЯ"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

            <TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Логин"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </TextInputLayout>

            <TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Пароль"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="@style/AppTheme.Button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Войти" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Мой контроллер класс

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import R;
import core.entity.User;
import core.service.UserService;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UserService.onResponseListener<User> {
    private final static String TAG = "LoginActivity";


    @BindView(R.id.email)
    EditText email;

    @BindView(R.id.password)
    EditText password;

    @BindView(R.id.loginForm)
    View loginForm;

    @BindView(R.id.progressBar)
    View progressBar;

    UserService.onCancelListener onCancelListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        if (UserService.getInstance().getUser() != null) {
            startMainActivity();
            return;
        }

        settings();
        setListeners();
    }

    private void startMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void settings() {
        email.requestFocus();
    }

    private void setListeners() {
        password.setOnEditorActionListener((textView, id, keyEvent) -> {
            auth();
            return false;
        });
    }

    public void auth() {
        String login = email.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String pass = password.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();

        if (login.isEmpty()) {
            email.setText("");
            email.setError("Введите имя пользователя");
            email.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (pass.isEmpty()) {
            password.setText("");
            password.setError("Введите пароль");
            password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(password.getWindowToken(), 0);

        loadStart();
        UserService.getInstance().auth(login, pass, this);
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.email_sign_in_button)
    public void onClick() {
        auth();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private void loadStart() {
        loginForm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void loadStop() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        loginForm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (onCancelListener != null)
            onCancelListener.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(User user) {
        startMainActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkError(Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        loadStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRowNotFound(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        email.setText("");
        email.setError(message);
        email.requestFocus();
        password.setText("");
        password.setError(message);
        loadStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(UserService.onCancelListener cl) {
        onCancelListener = cl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.TextInputLayout"` вот эта строка отправляется сразу же в гугл. Не помог гугл, добавляйте в вопрос содержимое `build.gradle`

Comment: Для вью-элементов не из стандартного фреймворка нужно писать полное имя (вместе с пакетом): `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev  Благодарью помогло